# Large state space and Markov decision process

Tags: machine-learning, markov-decision-process

I am working on a project where I have an MDP but with a very large state space (each state is described by a tuple (a,b,c,d) where a,b,c,d are integers in the range [0, 1000]). 
My goal is to compute the optimal policy (and I know the probability transitions), and of course it's doable using Dynamic Programming. However, this proves to be very slow given the really large state space.
Therefore, I was wondering what kind of techniques I could use to speed up the process.

I have seen value fitted iteration but even if I get the value function, I would have to look at the argmax and that would require looking at all the neighbour states.

Just to be more precise my framework is as follows: my states are described by s = (n,u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4) where n corresponds to some kind of time, u_i are quantities remaining (they represent remaining stocks) and therefore when going from n to n+1 , our stocks will be decreasing depending on the action chosen. (that's why I was considering integers for my problems). THerefore it is some kind of inventory problems with no refilling. What would be some approximation I could make?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How about using some fancy neural network architectures/cells like GRU and LSTM? For example, in this article (where they do not yet use LSTMs or so) http://karpathy.github.io/2016/05/31/rl/ I think they are implicitly solving this problem by letting a NN learn a representation of the state in a smaller (i.e. the size of the hidden Layer is smaller —> less dimensions) space...

Comment: What @FabianWerner is suggesting is one specific approach in the broad class of Approximate Dynamic Programming approaches; you might want to check out https://web.mit.edu/dimitrib/www/ADP_Short_Course_Complete.pdf and the book by Powell, who also provides us with http://adp.princeton.edu/Papers/Powell-NRLWhat%20you%20should%20know%20about%20approximate%20dynamic%20programming.pdf.   It's a large field with a lot of different techniques, far too many to enumerate here IMO, without a lot more information about your problem to limit the alternatives to something reasonable.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers and your reading suggestions! I'll look at that. Just to be more precise my framework is as follows: my states are described by s = (n,u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4) where n corresponds to some kind of time, u_i are quantities remaining (they represent remaining stocks) and therefore when going from n to n+1 , our stocks will be decreasing depending on the action chosen. (that's why I was considering integers for my problems). Idk if it's clearer now

Comment: An inventory problem, e.g., lost sales perhaps?  Techniques for some inventory, or more generally reservoir, problems are addressed specifically in Powell's book.

Comment: Yes exactly. Thanks a lot for the time taken to answer my questions!!

Comment: I have seen that the book is way too expensive for me to buy it (>100$) therefore could you tell me the names of some techniques that are used for the inventory/reservoir problem in Powell's book, so that I can look for them on the internet? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Markov processes tend to have same series of matrix multiplications that can be performance intensive, you can save the calculated matrix into a dictionary. read from it if it was calculated before, else calculate and save into the dictionary.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).